# Bad voice recording quality in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, audio-recording

Voice recording quite bad under 18.04. with a lot of background noise. The more I turn up mic volume, the louder noise is. Can I do something to get rid of the background noise? It only happens with Ubuntu and its based distroes. In Arch-based distroes recording is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be in LiveMode (with ReadOnly Overlay), check

```
/etc/speechd.conf
```

- comment out Line 267 `#Include "clients/*.conf"`
- activate Line 271 `DisableAutoSpawn`

SpeechDispatcher may create multiple InputDevice Instances from Templates (blocking the Buffer and disturbing the Realtime Pulseaudio).

Additionally check in *System settings* -> *Sound* -> *Applications* and remove (usually 3) Instances.